# TabWidget overlapping the tab content

Tags: android

In my TabHost activity, I want to show an ImageView below the selected tab (the ImageView overlaps the tab content). 
What would be the best solution to do this? 
I was thinking that creating a custom tab widget that can overlap the child activity layout may be a solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show for us your activity's layout

Comment: Right now, it's a regular TabHost activity layout. I didn't implemented the feature yet because I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

please checl my article on android tabs

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/tabbed-applications-in-android.html

Comment: I've read it. I'm using the TabHost with multiple activities. The thing is that my tab must overlap the tab content (the child activity layout) when it is selected by the user. Maybe an image would have helped, but I'm not allowed to upload any.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried padding, or setting the margin_layout attribute for the ImageView?

Comment: I don't think that would help. The thing is that when a tab gets selected an ImageView must be shown below that tab. I don't know if that image should be a part of the tab (this means that it would overlap the content layout) or if should be a part of the child activity layout (this means that the tab should command the child activity layout and specify where to place the ImageView depending on the tab's position)